# Is there a shortcut for \mathrm in AUCTeX?

Tags: key-bindings, auctex

Is there a build-in shortcut for inserting `\mathrm{}` and putting the cursor between `{}` in AUCTeX?

Comment: Try `C-c C-f C-r`; you can find the key sequence by looking at the "Insert Font" menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`C-c C-f C-r` will do it.  Check out [the AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Font-Specifiers.html) for the keybindings for all of the standards.