# A comprehensive list of shortcuts provided by AUCTeX

Tags: key-bindings, auctex

Is there a document (pdf if any) that contains a comprehensive list of all shortcuts provided by AUCTeX? I mean a kind of **AUCTEX Reference Card** but for all shortcuts.

This question is related to my previous question:

[Is there a shortcut for \mathrm in AUCTeX?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/is-there-a-shortcut-for-mathrm-in-auctex)

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/732/115 . My preferred [answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/734/115) from that Emacs SE question is to use the [`discover-my-major`](https://github.com/steckerhalter/discover-my-major) package (available on Melpa).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is an index of keybindings: it's in the index of the [AUCTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Indices).

Note: I got to this index by googling "auctex manual", opening up the first hit, which is the manual, selecting the HTML option (although any of them would work), selecting "Indices," and finally selecting "Key Index."

Likewise, a google search for "AUCTEX reference card", the phrase you asked about, turns up quite a lot of them.

Please consider doing a little background research in the relevant manual.  Although manuals vary in their comprehensiveness, and sometimes it's hard to know what to look for when the software does [something astonishing](http://xkcd.com/293/), keybindings are generally pretty well documented.

Comment: My software stabs me (in the back) all the time; and the feeling of betrayal always astonishes me: I guess I'm a slow learner...

Answer (score 7):

You can run <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to see the current bindings.

Answer (score 2):

The (currently) latest documentation for AUCTEX can be found here:

https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/auctex/12.3-extra/

The directory contains the manual (`auctex.pdf`) and reference card (`tex-ref.pdf`).  When a newer version is out by the time you read this, it can probably be found by clicking on `Parent Directory` and selecting the latest directory called something like `XX.Y-extra/`.

Comment: Note that the link in @dan's answer points to the manual for the current Auctex release, which gets updated for each release. Your link will always point to version 12.3. You can also get to the manual for the version of AUCTeX that is actually installed in your Emacs (whether or not it is current) from the built-in help system (`C-h i`)

Comment: @Tyler Indeed, it points to the manual, not the reference card with a comprehensive list as the OP requested.  A typical example of the difference between the two, is that in the key index of the manual the key `C-c C-f C-b` is 'explained' as "16, 23", while in the reference card the explanation reads "Insert bold text", which I find more comprehensive.  See the text below the link for steps to get to the latest version of the reference card.